# Cannot read a file from user in group

Tags: permissions, apache2, 22.04, chmod

I've a file which permission are `-rwxrwxr-x 1 an-user www-data 1094 Jun  9 09:42 myfile`

The group is www-data, so any one in the www-data group should be allowed.

When trying to read the file through sudo with `sudo -u www-data cat myfile` I've a permission denied.

`sudo groups www-data` confirm that www-data is in the www-data group.

Comment: 1) Why use `sudo` if the user has permissions? … 2) Did you manually create that user or you are using the already existing Apache user? … 3) What are the permissions of the file’s parent directory/s?

Comment: 1) I'm testing with sudo to simulate that apache access it 2) it's the apache user 3) permission are drwxrwxr-x an-user www-data

Comment: Please add the output of `stat myfile` and `file myfile` and `namei -l myfile` to your question by [edit]ing it.